# In dropdown menu main li parent pushing its siblings

Tags: jquery, css

I made a simple dropdown menu but the problem is the main `<li>` parent pushes its siblings after the dropdown effect.

So if you hover over `Drop 1`, then `Link 3` then `link 6`, `Drop 2` will get pushed to the right because `Drop 1` `li` will increase in width.

How to prevent this?

[FIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/ksXNL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position: absolute;` for the child elements and set the drop downs position as per your requirement.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksXNL/1/)

```
.menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

> Note: If you want, this can be accomplished with pure CSS, for the
>   question of smooth drop downs, you can use `CSS transitions`

Comment: I can't accept it until a certain amount of time passes, it is not possible. I always accept answers that fix the issue.

Comment: @DerekHenderson if you check out the user profile, he does accept the answers, probably, it's the 15min rule which is restricting him to accept the answer :)

Comment: @DerekHenderson he he thank you, btw you should fix your selector, you have 2 `li`, should be just 1 :)

Comment: No, no, that second li is deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position: absolute` for your last list:

```
.menu > li li ul {
    position: absolute;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ksXNL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ksXNL/3/

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    display: table;
    float:left;
}

.menu li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    list-style: none;
    width:100px;
}
.menu li a{
    background:red;
}
.menu li ul{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0px;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
}
.menu li li{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
.menu li ul li a{
    background:green;
}
```